# Who is the "Cursed Child" in "Harry Potter and the Cursed Child"?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

The new Harry Potter play is called "[Harry Potter and the Cursed Child](https://www.pottermore.com/cursed-child)" and while there seem to be a number of potential candidates for the title character, is there any indication of **who the titular 'Cursed Child' actually is?**

**Is it Albus Potter, Scorpius Malfoy or *someone else entirely?***

Comment: dam kindles search not working

Comment: are you asking this because you have read it and are not clear? or because you have not read it?

Comment: @HorusKol - I've read it. There seems an obvious choice but I'm struggling to find anything in the text (or interviews) that specifically confirms it.

Comment: @Valorum - Who would you say is the obvious choice?

Comment: @Adamant - I think you've hit the nail on the head.

Comment: +1; just finished the book and came here to ask this. Glad I'm not the only one. There's also a good summary of the options [here](http://www.hypable.com/cursed-child-harry-potter-delphie-albus-scorpius/) which also proposes 'Cedric Diggory', 'Rose' (sarcastically) and 'all of them' as possible answers.

Comment: It's the audience.

Answer (score 18):

### There could be more than one

JKR has at least [confirmed](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/634663427684876288?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) that Tom Riddle is *not* the cursed  child:

> Good theory, because I do think Tom was cursed in the way that you
>  suggest, but no, he's not the child

That said, the phrase "cursed child" is a bit playful. It could apply to numerous characters, probably intentionally so.

- **Harry Potter**

  He was imbued with a portion of Voldemort's soul as a baby, so that definitely fits. There are some scenes in the play when Harry appears as a child, including this one:

  > AUNT PETUNIA: We’re cursed! He’s cursed us! **The boy has cursed us!**
  >  (Seeing YOUNG HARRY.) This is all your fault. Get back in your hole.
- **Albus Severus Potter**

  Albus is metaphorically cursed both with the Potter family legacy, and with the burden of being sorted into Slytherin. Bane also refers to him as having a "black cloud" around, presumably referring to him being "cursed" with an unpleasant future.

  > BANE: There is a black cloud around your son, a dangerous black
  >  cloud.
  >  
  >  HARRY: Around Albus?
  >  
  >  BANE: A black cloud that may endanger us all. You’ll find your son
  >  again, Harry Potter. But then you could lose him forever.
- **Scorpius Malfoy**

  He has to deal with the "curse" of the Malfoy family legacy, and with unfounded rumors that he is the son of Voldemort. In addition, he may possess a more literal curse, inherited from his mother.

  > DRACO: We were capable of having children but Astoria was frail. A blood
  >  malediction, a serious one. An ancestor was cursed . . . it showed up
  >  in her. You know how these things can resurface after generations . .

But the best candidate is probably:

- **Delphini "Diggory"**

  > Delphini is the probable daughter of Lord Voldemort and Bellatrix
  >  Lestrange.  She is thus cursed with Voldemort's legacy and powers,
  >  including Parseltongue, as well as that of her mother.

Comment: You might want to consider this image as well; http://images.amcnetworks.com/bbcamerica.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/harrypottercc.jpg

Comment: The red hair made me think it was likely to be Albus

Comment: @Valorum - Even if it is, it could merely reflect his status as the main-ish character.

Comment: @Valorum while the hair boesn't look _blonde_ (like Scorpious), it also doesn't look _red_ either (to me). Also, why would red hair make you think it was likely to be Albus? Albus has _brown_ hair, not red. [Also, it could even be argued that it's a little _girl_, possibly pointing to Delphi. My point is that I don't think there's enough to know for sure who the person on the cover is :)]

Comment: @RedCaio - The actor they cast to play Albus *in the play* has dark hair. The actor they cast to play [Albus in the film](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/5/5f/Albus-Potter_DH2.png/revision/latest?cb=20160712021930) looks a hell of a lot like the kid on [the poster](http://images.amcnetworks.com/bbcamerica.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/harrypottercc.jpg) and has slightly red hair. Also, the poster was drawn before the role was cast...

Comment: I agree with this answer. I think that the title of the play is a multiple entendre. I would like to include Astoria herself as a "cursed child" as she was literally cursed generationally and passed early. I don't think it refers to Tom Riddle, nor does it refer to Harry, because it wouldn't make much sense with the title of the play. Replace "Cursed Child" with one of the candidates and HP makes little sense: "Harry Potter and the Cursed Harry Potter". Overall, Delphini is the "main" cursed child, however.

Comment: Why is Bellatrix adulterous? (Haven't heard this before)

Answer (score 3):

I completely agree with Valorum and Adamant when they say there are many candidates.

Adamant explains very well in what way each of them could be seen as cursed.

### But I think the right one is Delphini.

Because of another clue:

The cover of the book shows a pic (also shown inside the book, on the website and so on). It's kinf of the logo of this book.

And what is it? an Augurey. The bird, Delphini has a tattoo of. The bird of her guardian. Her nickname in her best-loved alternate reality.

Comment: The child in the picture on the cover appears to be Albus Potter though.